# Vaadin's RichTextArea doesn't seem to respect any css properties after all: unset;

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

If I have:

```
<style>
    .special
    {
        all: unset;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
</style>

<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>4</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td class="special">5</td></tr></table>
```

The last table will not get a width of 100% although it should. I've tested this snippet in FF, Chrome, etc., and they all seem to work but for whatever reason the Vaadin `RichTextArea` doesn't. What happens is that no styles are applied, everything is unset.

With that in mind is there a way to unset the css properties for a specific element to guarantee a specific look for that element (in this case table) because the generated html may have the following:

```
<style>
    table
    {
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px dashed #ddd;
    }
</style>
```